# combinational sum calculation issue

Tags: c++, algorithm

Working on below problem and post the code. The confusion is, it seems there is no need to check `(!target) && (!need)`, and using `(!target)` itself is fine? But how do we guarantee there are always **exact** k numbers in the results? I tried a few, but it seems working without add condition of `&& (!need)`. If anyone have any good thoughts, it will be great. Thanks.

Find all possible combinations of k numbers that add up to a number n, given that only numbers from 1 to 9 can be used and each combination should be a unique set of numbers.

Ensure that numbers within the set are sorted in ascending order.

Example 1:

Input: k = 3, n = 7

Output:

```
[[1,2,4]]
```

Example 2:

Input: k = 3, n = 9

Output:

```
[[1,2,6], [1,3,5], [2,3,4]]
```

Code,

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > combinationSum3(int k, int n) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > res;
        std::vector<int> combination;
        combinationSum3(n, res, combination, 1, k);
        return res;
    }
private:
    void combinationSum3(int target, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &res, std::vector<int> &combination, int begin, int need) {
        if (!target) {
            res.push_back(combination);
            return;
        }
        else if (!need)
            return;
        for (int i = begin; i != 10 && target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2; ++i) {
            combination.push_back(i);
            combinationSum3(target - i, res, combination, i + 1, need - 1);
            combination.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only (!target) is enough because the condition `target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2`.  `target == 0` implies that `target == i` in the last step, also note `target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2`, so we can assert that `need == 1` when `target == i && target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2`

Comment: looks like the test case if not enough? Try https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iii/, and the code I posted can pass the testing. :)

Comment: I see:) I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks zhiwenf, what do you mean? Anything in your original post is wrong? :)

Comment: Thanks zhiwenf, could you elaborate a bit more how do you draw conclusion of  "need == 0 when target == i && target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2"?

Comment: it should be  target == i && target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2 implies that need == 1. if need > 1, target > 2* i > i.

Comment: Hi zhiwenf, why "target == i && target >= i * need + need * (need - 1) / 2 implies that need == 1", a bit more details are appreciated?

Comment: if `target == i`, set target = `i`, you get `i >= i * need + need*(need-1)/2`, it is true only if `need <= 1`.

Comment: Thanks zhiwenf, (1) I am still confused what is the logical meaning of "need * (need - 1) / 2", it is the value of sum from 1 to (need-1), not sure how it related to the loop here. (2) Another issue is, not sure why we need i * need, does it mean we can select element i multiple times? I think the problem needs to select unique numbers in each combination.

Comment: I think it is `i + (i+1) + (i+2) + ... + (i+need-1)`. It means that `target` should be equal to or greater than the sum of the following `need` numbers.